# Python openpyxl.formatting.rule and Excel formula with variable as value

Tags: python, excel, formatting, openpyxl

I don’t know if somebody have already used the openpyxl.formatting.rule and Excel formula containing a variable as value

I cannot find a solution to put a variable as value in an Excel formula
When I set the real value, the formula is well taken into account and the result is the expected one
When I set a variable (as an argument of the function), the formula doesn’t recognize the value which is a string and my Excel file isn’t updated as expected.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension, DimensionHolder
from openpyxl.styles import Color, Fill, Font, PatternFill
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
...

def add_title_in_sheet(worksheet, title, ref_build,size_value):
 …
# for lines containing values for reference build
reference_fill = PatternFill(bgColor="00FFFF")
dxf = DifferentialStyle(fill=reference_fill)
rule2 = Rule( type="expression", dxf=dxf)
**rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2021 R2_B20210527", $C5))']  # Work well**
**rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ref_build, $C5))']            # Cannot work** 
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add('A5:G200', rule2)
```

In main python program:

```
wb = writer.book
add_title_in_sheet( wb['Measures'], "List of measures","2021 R2_B20210527", 14 )
```

Note: I’ve tried many writing but all not worked

```
rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ref_build, $C5))']
ou
rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ref_build”, $C5))']
ou
rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH({ref_build}, $C5))']
ou
rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH(‘ref_build’, $C5))']
ou
rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH(“{ref_build}”, $C5))']
```

Who has a solution?

Why I don't put directly the value? It is because it is retrieved in an Excel cell before.
Note: this function is used in a python program using panda, dataframe, read_excel with openpyxl engine.

Thanks a for your help,

Comment: What is `ref_build`? You probably want something like `f"ISNUMBER(SEARCH{ref_build})"`

Comment: Yes. ref_build contains the value passed in argument of my function. It is the variable.

Comment: I've also tried this solution: rule2.formula = ['ISNUMBER(SEARCH(f“{ref_build}”, $C5))'] but it doesn't work. 
<<You probably want something like f"ISNUMBER(SEARCH{ref_build})">> My answer is "Yes, I would like something like that".

Comment: Embedding the f-string within another string won't work.